# Synchronizing iPhone and Mail.app inboxes

Tags: email, iphone

I have IMAP configured on both my iPhone 3G and MacBook and I have push enabled on my iPhone.

When I receive an email and read it on my MacBook, shouldn't it mark it as unread on the iPhone too?

I didn't really notice it before, but recently, it has been annoying me that once I have viewed them on my MacBook I have to view them on my iPhone to mark then as read.
Just *checking for new mail* in the iPhone doesn't suffice.

Is there a way to make sure the changes on the Mail.app inbox are applied immediately to the iPhone?

I have my own email servers on my own domain(maquib.com hosted on dreamhost). My brother who also has an account and configured the same way has also noticed this.

Here are some screenshots of how my iPhone and Mac are configured:
[image: Mac]
[image: iPhone 1][image: iPhone 2][image: iPhone 4]

Comment: I *think* I've understood and correctly translated what you meant. If not, make the necessary modifications.

Comment: @dean And we need more information, what type of account is this? Gmail? I've noticed that when I have Gmail on push on my phone, the changes are not applied if I open a new mail on the MacBook directly after receiving it. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a fix for that.

Comment: Sounds like less of a problem with your mail clients and more of a problem with the IMAP server configuration.

Comment: @Graham Theres not much to configure with the imap the username,password and server. It tells me that its using IMAP in the settings.

Comment: @dean can you post some screenshot? of both the iPhone and you Mac setup.

Comment: @Loïc Wolff I've added pics of what I think is relevant. If theres anything else I will add to them.

Comment: @dean Thanks. First of all, you don't have push notification. See on the last picture? If you had push, there would have been a "Push" entry to select. Since you don't have it, it's just fetching every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's an iPhone configuration problem.

Maybe a Mail.app problem, it seems it's no syncing back the changes correctly. Except I don't think there's a preference to change that.

**It's most likely a server configuration problem.**
To be sure, we'll need more information about your mail servers. Do you have access to the configuration? What is maquib.com? From the look of it, it looks like your personal server (with a project to make a Mac OS Tiger app!)

---

Can you try to download [**Sparrow**](http://sparrowmailapp.com)? (there's a free version)
Add your account on it and see if the problem is still there. That way we'll know if the problem is on the server or on the software side.

Comment: How would it be a server error if it works by reading it on the iPhone and it shows read on the mac? Plus the idea of IMAP is that it connects with the server to view the email.

Comment: I will try with thunderbird i HATE anything to do with the app store.

Comment: With thunderbird its worked as it should. Saying that there is a fault with the mac set up.

Comment: Right this is weird i've changed nothing all is back as it was before and is now working correctly. This is strange :S.

Comment: Yeah we haven't updated the site since tiger was around :L as I mainly lost interest in coding for OS X as I started using Linux more :D.